# Android ProgreesBar Only show progress strip without the background rectangular box

Tags: java, android, android-styles

[image]

As you can see Progress Bar in above image has blue strip in the middle which is progress indicator & around this progress indicator there is a black box. In my application I want this progress bar only as blue strip progress indicator without the sorruonding black box. The progress bar with style `Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal` shows only progress indicator but its not thin as progress bar style `Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontalrizontal`. I wnat it like image shown below. I have gone thourhg the reference doc for progress bar but didn't find anything. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) So is there any xml attribute that just disappears or hides the surrounding black box ? 
[image]

Comment: You have to enclose the progress bar xml tag inside another LinearLayout tag. In your Linear Layout tag define the rectangular length and width and background color.

Comment: @all I appreciate your suggestions but I don't want any background at all I just want blue progress strip.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     <!-- SPECIFY HERE YOUR BACKGROUND, LENGTH AND WIDTH  -->
     ... >
     <ProgressBar
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/loading" />
 </LinearLayout>
```